# Error when creating directory and then opening a file within it in Python, but no error if directory already exists

Tags: python, subprocess

I expect a directory to be created and then a file to be opened within it for writing to when I execute my code below in Python 2.6.6,

```
import subprocess

def create_output_dir(work_dir):
    output_dir = '/work/m/maxwell9/some_name5/'
    subprocess.Popen(['mkdir', output_dir])
    return output_dir

if __name__ == '__main__':
    work_dir = '/work/m/maxwell9/'
    output_dir = create_output_dir(work_dir)
    #output_dir = '/work/m/maxwell9/some_name5/'
    filename = output_dir + 'bt.sh'
    with open(filename, 'w') as script:
        print('there')
```

but instead I get the error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "slurm_test.py", line 13, in <module>
    with open(filename, 'w') as script:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/work/m/maxwell9/some_name5/bt.sh'
```

If I run the script, I can then see that the directory is created. If I then uncomment the line,

```
#output_dir = '/work/m/maxwell9/some_name5/'
```

and comment the line,

```
output_dir = create_output_dir(work_dir)
```

then the file is output fine. So there is something about creating the folder and then writing to it in the same script that is causing an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`subprocess.Popen` starts up an external process but doesn't wait for it to complete unless you tell it to (e.g. by calling [`.wait`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) on the returned `Popen` instance).  Most likely, `mkdir` is in the process of creating a directory while `open(filename, 'w')` attempts to create a file in that directory.  This is an example of a ["race condition"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).

The solution is to `.wait` on the open process (as noted above), or you can use one of the convenience wrappers `subprocess.check_output`, [`subprocess.check_call`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) or (even better), you can avoid `subprocess` entirely by using [`os.mkdir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.mkdir) or `os.makedirs`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `os` library instead of `subprocess`, which makes for a more straightforward implementation. Try swapping out your `create_output_dir` function  with this:

```
import os 

def create_output_dir(work_dir):   
    try:
        os.makedirs(work_dir)
    except OSError:
        pass

    return work_dir
```

Comment: You're probably better off using `try: os.makedirs(work_dir); except OSError: pass` rather than `os.path.isdir` (avoids another minor race condition).